# How to update the Fullcalendar in my function?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How to update the Fullcalendar in my function? (onClick, onSelect, function(), etc)

example https://codepen.io/liggth/pen/GRgjYqG?editors=1010

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    editable: true,
  });

  calendar.render();


});

function test(){
   calendar.refetchEvents(); 
}
```

IN this case, I get the error:
Uncaught TypeError: calendar.refetchEvents is not a function

Comment: It's a scope error - `calendar` is out of scope when you call it from the `test` function. You need to make it global. You should just variable scope a bit more, so that you understand it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add property as dateClick and assign function in it. [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/handlers)

```
var calendar;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    editable: true,
     dateClick: function() {
    alert('a day has been clicked!');
  }

  });

  calendar.render();


});

  function test() {
     calendar.refetchEvents();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But I do not understand you. In your example, I still get the same error:  Uncaught TypeError: calendar.refetchEvents is not a function